# How to prove that $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[k]{a+x_n}$ is bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $k\in\mathbb N$ with $k\ge2$ and fix $a>0$. Let $x_1=\sqrt[k]{a}$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[k]{a+x_n}$. I want to prove that this sequence is bounded above.

My proof is by induction. Suppose that $L>0$ be such that $L^k=L+a$. If $n=1$, then $x_1=\sqrt[k]{a}\le L$, since $a\le a+L$. So if $x_n\le L$, then we have

$$x_{n+1}^k=x_n+a\le L+a=L^k$$

and so $x_{n+1}\le L$.

But I don't know how to justify if such a $L$ exists. So I think maybe there is some better ways. So my main question is,

What other methods can we use to prove that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that we want to prove $|x_n|\leq L$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. We would like to prove it by induction, since your sequence is given recursively. But, here's the thing, we don't know what $L$ we should choose yet, so we will try to go through the inductive proof first and see what $L$ will allow us to get through it.

Assume that we have $|x_n|\leq L$ and we want to prove that it implies $|x_{n+1}| \leq L$. We have

$$|x_{n+1}|\leq L \iff |x_{n+1}|^k\leq L^k \iff |x_n + a| \leq L^k$$

and the question is what can we use to prove $|x_n+a|\leq L^k$. We know that $|x_n|\leq L$, so one should think of triangle inequality: $|x_n + a|\leq |x_n|+|a|\leq L + |a|$. Now we see that it is sufficient to find $L$ such that $$L + |a| \leq L^k.\tag{1}$$ We also need to have $|x_1| = |\sqrt[k]a| \leq L$, so we might want to try $L = |\sqrt[k]a|$ in $(1)$. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The next obvious thing to try is $L = |a|$. In that case $(1)$ becomes $$|a|+|a| \leq |a|^k \iff |a|^{k-1} \geq 2.$$ Ah, so now we know that $L = |a|$ works for $|a| \geq 2$ (this is a crude estimate, but we don't really want to depend on $k$). And what about $|a|< 2$? Since $2$ seems to be the magical number here, why don't we try $L = 2$:

$$2+|a| < 2 + 2 \leq 2^k,\ k\geq 2.$$

Great, it works.

Finally, we see that $L = \max\{|a|,2\}$ will do the job and let us prove the boundedness by induction.

Hopefully, this sheds some light onto how someone can stumble upon seemingly unmotivated bounds in analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Since we actually just need $L+a\le L^k$ in your induction we could find an explicit $L$ depending on $a$ :

- If $0 \lt a \le 2$ then choose $L=2$ so we have 
  $$a+L \le 4 \le 2^k = L^k$$
- If $ 2 \le a$ then choose $L=a$ so that
  $$ a + L = 2a \le a^2 \le a^k = L^k$$
  since $k \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is actually very well put!

To prove the existence of $L>0$ such that $L^k-L=a$ just consider $f:x\mapsto x^k-x$, it is continuous, $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$. Then, using the theorem of intermediate values: $$\forall a>0, \exists L>0,f(L)=L^k-L=a$$

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this will not answer your question, but it will allow you to prove that there exists $L > 0$ such that $L^k=L+a$.

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$g(x) = x^k - x - a.$$
Then $g$ is continuous, $g(0) < 0$, and $$g(x) \rightarrow \infty, \quad x\rightarrow \infty, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Here it is important that $k > 1$. In particular, $g$ assumes both positive and negative values on the *positive* real line. It follows that $g$ as at least one zero $L > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the positive root of
$f(x)
=x^k-x-a$
where $a > 0$,
note that
$f(0) = -a$,
$f(1) = -a$,
and,
by Bernoulli's inequality,
$f(1+a)
\ge 1+ka-1-a-a
=a(k-2)
\ge 0$
since
$k \ge 2$.

Therefore $f$ has a root
between $1$ and $1+a$.

Also,
$f'(x)
=kx^{k-1}-1
\gt 0$
for $x \ge 1$
so $f$ has at most one root
for $x \ge 1$.

Therefore
$f$ has exactly one root
for $x \ge 1$
and that root is in
$[1, 1+a]$.
Call this root
$x_a$.

Also,
$f''(x) = k(k-1)x^{k-2}
\gt 0$
for
$x > 0$
so
$f'(x)$ is increasing for
$x > 0$.
Since
$f'(1) = k$,
$f'(x) \gt k$
for $x \gt 1$.

Let's do a Newton
and find a better approximation
to that root.
This actually is not needed,
but I like doing it.

Newton's iteration is

$\begin{array}\\
x-\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
&=x-\dfrac{x^k-x-a}{kx^{k-1}-1}\\
&=\dfrac{x(kx^{k-1}-1)-(x^k-x-a)}{kx^{k-1}-1}\\
&=\dfrac{kx^{k}-x-x^k+x+a}{kx^{k-1}-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(k-1)x^{k}+a}{kx^{k-1}-1}\\
\end{array}
$

For $x=1$ this is
$\dfrac{(k-1)+a}{k-1}
=1+\dfrac{a}{k-1}
$.
By Bernoulli, again,
$f(1+\frac{a}{k-1})
=(1+\frac{a}{k-1})^k-(1+\frac{a}{k-1})-a
\ge 1+k\frac{a}{k-1}-(1+\frac{a}{k-1})-a
= 0
$,
so the root is in
$[1, 1+\frac{a}{k-1}]$.

Back to the
relevant stuff.

Since
$f'(x_a) > 0$,
if
$x > x_a$
then
$f(x) > 0$
so
$x^k > x+a$
or
$x > \sqrt[k]{x+a}$.
Therefore the iteration
$x_{n+1}
=\sqrt[k]{x_n+a}
$
decreases if
$x_n > x_a$.

Also,
if
$x_{n+1} < x_a$
then
$\sqrt[k]{x_n+a}
\lt x_a
$
or
$x_n+a < x_a^k
=x_a+a$
(since
$x_a^k-x_a-a=0$)
or
$x_n < x_a$,
which contradicts the assumption that
$x_n > x_a$.
Therefore,
$x_n > x_a$
implies that
$x_a < x_{n+1} < x_n$,
so the iterations
decrease and are
bounded below by $x_a$.

Similarly,
if
$1 < x_n < x_a$
then
the iterations
increase and are
bounded above by $x_a$.

I will leave to you
the proof that
the iterations
actually converge to $x_a$.
Hint:
$f'(x) > 0$
for $x \ge 1$.